# TypeScript mapped type to represent an object with optional Observables (with string literal mapped keys)

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I need a mapped type to represent an object where the properties are optionally RxJS Observables.

The simplest and easiest way to achieve that is with this type:

```
type OptionalObservables<T> = {
   [K in keyof T]: T[K] | Observable<T[K]>
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
const animal: OptionalObservables<Animal> = {

    species: 'dog',
    noise: of('bark')     // RxJS Observable that satisfies Observable<string>
}
```

(I have a separate function to parse an object and subscribe to the observables. But this question isn't really about the RxJS aspect of it.)

However... I generally prefer to use the `$` suffix convention when it comes to observables so what I really want is when choosing an observable I'd like to have a $ at the end of the key. Manipulations like this are possible with [Key Remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

```
{
    species: 'dog',
    noise$: of('bark')  
}
```

Getting everything working together proved to be much harder that I expected!

The ultimate type I need to end up with for `OptionalObservables<{ species: string, noise: string }>` would be this:

```
// species as a string or observable
({ species: string } | { species$: Observable<string> }) &

// noise as a string or observable
({ noise: string } | { noise$: Observable<string> })
```

(Where each property K of T is required and can either be of type T[K] or Observable<T[K]>).

---

The closest I've got as a foundation is something like this:

```
type OptionalObservables<T> = 
{
   [K in keyof T]: K extends string ? 

                   // the original property name and type
                   { [P in K]: T[K] } 

                   |

                   // OR the original property name with $ suffix and Observable type
                   { [P in `${K}\$`]: Observable<T[K]> }  
                   : never
}
```

This adds an extra level of 'nesting' (but otherwise fulfills my requirements) so I end up with this:

```
{
    species: {
        species: "cat" | "dog";
    } | 
    {
        species$: Observable<"cat" | "dog">;
    };

    noise: {
        noise: "bark" | "meow";
    } | 
    {
        noise$: Observable<"bark" | "meow">;
    };
}
```

I was hoping that getting this far would allow me to use something like [Unionize](https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/05/12/unionize-objectify/) to pull out the values and merge them back together without the extra level. So far I've only managed to get ALL the possible properties to be required or all to be optional!

If there's a trick I'm missing or it's not possible - but would love to be able to get this working.

An alternative might be a way to validate the structure is compatible with a method instead relying just on a mapped type.

Answer (score 1):

You requirement is really rare. But it's not impossible.

We need use some dark magic in typescript. But as you know, don't use dark magic lightly.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#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-CoSgHivkWXFDvG8hpe3t+CSA8B7UbC40i+o5uMAACMmgtjY5ABPY86zjeMGLhsUHih+9A3neHiIdEf7CABeRfAATGBE62Ge8HuHBe5+IhZ5PgwciKO+EQeGomG-v+wCAV8ADMREQUhZFzpRGFIbRaEoRhUDDlAyTSN0LBYexnHAAALLx+z8ZRdECAxZHMVsUkyT0IkoWE4mYUAA)

### Code

```
type Observable<T> = {value: T}

declare function of<T>(t:T): Observable<T>

type Animal = {
    species: 'species'
    noise: 'noise'
}

type Unwrap<T> = T extends [any] ? T[0] : T

type SingleOptionalObservables<K extends keyof any, V> = { [T in K]: V } | { [T in K as `${string & T}\$`]: Observable<V> }

type SingleOptionalObservablesByKey<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends any ? [SingleOptionalObservables<K, T[K]>] : never

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type OptionalObservables<T> = Unwrap<UnionToIntersection<SingleOptionalObservablesByKey<T, keyof T>>>

type OOA = OptionalObservables<Animal>

// type OOA = ({species: 'species'} | {species$: Observable<'species'>}) & 
//            ({noise: 'noise'} | {noise$: Observable<'noise'>})

const test1: OOA = {
    species: 'species',
    noise: 'noise',
}

const test2: OOA = {
    species: 'species',
    noise$: of('noise'),
}

const test3: OOA = {
    species: 'species',
    noise$: 'noise', // wrong
}

const test4: OOA = {
    species: of('species'), // wrong
    noise: 'noise',
}
```

### Steps

1. Extract the type's keys
2. Map the key type to target union type distributedly
3. Wrap each part as tuple to avoid it be changed in next step
4. Change the union type to intersection type
5. Unwrap the tuple type, it is the answer

### Issue

Although we defined the correct type, typescript doesn't support such intersection of union types. Following usage is still allowed.

```
const test: OOA = {
    species: 'species',
    noise$: of('noise'),
    noise: 'noise',
}
```

I think there must be an open issue for typescript but I haven't find it. It  may be fixed in future release.